# Excel formula to copy 1st Column A value for successive identical Column B values; then repeat for next Column B value

Tags: excel, excel-formula, copy, calculated-columns

Below, on the left (headed "BEFORE") is a small extract from a large (20,000 row) Excel spreadsheet.  The 2 columns have been sorted on the "Name" column value.

I want the "ID" column value to be the same for each distinct entry in the "Name" column; for example by taking the first-occurring "ID" column value for each name and writing that value into the "ID" column for each successive occurrence of the same distinct Name.  The extract on the right (headed "AFTER") shows the result I'm looking for.

Is there a way to do this with an Excel formula?

[image: Excel sample]

Comment: You can use INDEX/MATCH of the name on the name column to find the first occurrence and return its corresponding ID.

Comment: Thank you.  I've never heard of those two functions, but I've looked them up just now and they do indeed look promising.  I'll post back when I get it working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @BigBen suggested you can use `INDEX/MATCH` combination like below-

```
=INDEX($A$2:$A$8,MATCH(E2,$B$2:$B$8,0))
```

You can use `XLOOKUP()` if you have <kbd>Excel365</kbd>.

```
=XLOOKUP(E2,$B$2:$B$8,$A$2:$A$8)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you.  With a minor amount of experimental fiddling I got it to work.